# Retrofit2 GET annotations dynamic url

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I need help as I have experience in Android Development with Java language and I have a little bit of experience in Kotlin. I am stuck on a code where I am using the retrofit library and for communication with the server and I want to add the variable in the GET annotation of the retrofit from the constructor of the class but I couldn't do it, so please help me in this.

I will show my code below:

```
class UniSearchModel(private val country:String) {

interface UniServices {
    @GET("get_uni_of_country.php?country=$country")
    fun viewEvent(): Call<List<UniResponse>>

  }
}
```

Now what I want to do is that I want to add this country variable from the constructor into this annotation to make it dynamic URL but it gives me two error:

1. An annotation argument must be compile-time constant.
2. Unresolved reference: country

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a special @Query annotation.

So you should do it like this:

```
class UniSearchModel(private val country:String) {

  interface UniServices {

     @GET("get_uni_of_country.php")

     fun viewEvent(@Query("country")  country: String): Call<List<UniResponse>>

  }
}
```

Comment: It giving me an error at the line @Query that is 
A type annotation is required on a value parameter

Comment: Thanks, it's working but I got an error somewhere else I will show you

    uniService.viewEvent().enqueue(object : Callback<List<UniResponse>>

This is the part where I am waiting for response but at viewEvent() it showing error that NO VALUE PASSED FOR PARAMETER 'country'

Comment: Well you need to set a country (String) in viewEvent function.

Comment: Thanks that is fixed but I got one more problem, can you help me in that please.

Now I am getting an error from retrofit that is Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at path $ even though I have changed my response data structure to INT but it is giving me same error.

Comment: I think you have a parsing error. Try getting an example response and use some online tool to make a data class for your response.

Comment: Before using this way ou just suggested me I was using hardcoded url, so it was working fine but after changing now it is giving this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196629/discussion-between-alex-and-anas-reza).